# How do I match between two closing tags with regex in php?

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I have a piece of HTML (*NOT* a full HTML document) that has a few instances of the following:

```
    </div>




            some text is here

    </h3>
```

I'd like to match 'some text is here' only but am having trouble understanding multiple lines, line breaks and spaces with php regex. What I got is:

```
    preg_match('/<\/div>[\s\r\n\t]*(.*)[\s\n\r\t]*<\/h3>/', $string, $matches);
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I tried using DOMDocument() as well but it's throwing all sorts of errors, probably because this is not a full HTML document.

Any ideas??

Comment: Use an HTML parser.  You say that DOMDocument() is "throwing all sorts of errors," so I suggest you delete this question and post a new one with your DOMDocument() problem with the errors and let's fix that.  Rather than help you use the wrong tool for the job, it'd be better to help you use the right one.

Comment: How is it not working? It seems to work fine for me. Did you inspect `$matches[1]`?

Comment: @AndyLester I could be mistaken, but as I said in my post, this is not a full HTML document, and it even has extra data in it that is not HTML. If I could in fact use DOMDoc on it, I would be interested in seeing your example code, but I spent a good amount of time on it already and figured I'd just go the easy route. Alas, ExplosionPills answer worked out perfectly for my needs.

Comment: Have you looked at simplehtmldom?  I'm led to believe it is more robust than DOMDocument. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've looked at it in the past and never quite had time to figure out how to use it, but I figured it out now and it's much better for my overall project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
preg_match("@</div>(.*?)</h3>@s", $html, $matches);
```

The `s` PCRE modifier (after the last `@`) allows the `.` to match newlines.  The `.*?` is done so that it will only match up to the *first* `</h3>` instead of the last.  The data between the tags will be in `$matches[1]`